# How to center a rotated table in the page

Tags: tables, koma-script, minipage, rotating

I need to import a lot of Microsoft word tables in the appendix of my  `scrbook` document. I used Writer2Latex Libreoffice extension to convert them, I had to rotate them, because the original tables are in a landscape orientation, while my document is portrait. I managed to find this suitable solution thanks to the help of many of you:

```
% This file was converted to LaTeX by Writer2LaTeX ver. 1.6.1
% see http://writer2latex.sourceforge.net for more info
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\hypersetup{pdftex, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, filecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue, pdftitle=, pdfauthor=, pdfsubject=, pdfkeywords=}
% Text styles
\newcommand\textstyleEmphasis[1]{\textit{#1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\arraybslash{\let\\\@arraycr}
\makeatother
% Page layout (geometry)
\setlength\voffset{-1in}
\setlength\hoffset{-1in}
\setlength\topmargin{2cm}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{2cm}
\setlength\textheight{17.001cm}
\setlength\textwidth{25.7cm}
\setlength\footskip{0.0cm}
\setlength\headheight{0cm}
\setlength\headsep{0cm}
% Footnote rule
\setlength{\skip\footins}{0.119cm}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vspace*{-0.018cm}\setlength\leftskip{0pt}\setlength\rightskip{0pt plus 1fil}\noindent\textcolor{black}{\rule{0.25\columnwidth}{0.018cm}}\vspace*{0.101cm}}
% Pages styles
\makeatletter
\newcommand\ps@Standard{
  \renewcommand\@oddhead{}
  \renewcommand\@evenhead{}
  \renewcommand\@oddfoot{}
  \renewcommand\@evenfoot{}
  \renewcommand\thepage{\arabic{page}}
}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{Standard}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1mm}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{2022-01-01}
\begin{document}
\clearpage\setcounter{page}{1}\pagestyle{Standard}

\bigskip

\rotatebox{90}{%
    \begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft}
\tablefirsthead{}
\tablehead{}
\tabletail{}
\tablelasttail{}
\begin{tabular}{|m{3.6139998cm}|m{7.1060004cm}|m{7.0880003cm}m{7.09cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|m{25.498001cm}|}{\textbf{Studio:} Forbes SS \textit{et al.} Meta-analysis of randomized controlled
trials comparing open and laparoscopic ventral and incisional hernia repair with mesh. British Journal of Surgery
2009.}\\\hline
\textbf{Disegno dello studio}

 \textbf{Livello di evidenza} &
\textbf{Dettagli dello studio/limitazione} &
\multicolumn{1}{m{7.0880003cm}|}{\textbf{Caratteristiche dei pazienti}} &
\textbf{Interventi}\\\hline
\textbf{Disegno dello studio:}

Systematic review e meta-analisi di RCTs

~

\textbf{Certezza delle prove:}

Bassa

~
 &
\textbf{Paesi:} Non applicabile

\textbf{Centri:} Non applicabile

\textbf{Setting: }Ernie ventrali primitive e incisionali

\textbf{Finanziamento}: Non riportato

\textbf{Tasso di dropout: }Non applicabile

\textbf{Limitazioni}:

\textbf{Critical appraisal: }AMSTAR II

~
 &
\multicolumn{1}{m{7.0880003cm}|}{Pazienti con ernia ventrale primaria o ernia incisionale

~

\textbf{Ricerca bibliografica: }Gennaio 1950 -- Gennaio 2009

~

\textbf{Criteri di inclusione: }Studi prospettici randomizzati comparanti la tecnica laparoscopica con quella open,
entrambe con l'utilizzo di protesi

~

\textbf{Criteri di esclusione:} Studi focalizzati sulla riparazione di ernie inguinali, interventi senza protesi} &
Tecnica di riparazione laparoscopica vs. a cielo aperto con utilizzo di protesi\\\hline
\textbf{Note}: &
\multicolumn{3}{m{21.683998cm}|}{\textbf{Studi inclusi:} Asencio 2008, Barbaros 2007, Carbajo 1999, Misra 2006,
Moreno-Egea 2002, Navarra 2007, Olmi 2007, Pring 2008}\\\hline
\textbf{Outcomes} &
{}- Recidiva erniaria

{}- Durata dell'intervento chirurgico

{}- Durata dell'ospedalizzazione

{}- Tempo di ritorno a lavoro

{}- Sieroma

{}- Complicanze emorragiche

{}- Lesioni intestinali

{}- Infezione di ferita con espianto della protesi

{}- Infezione di ferita senza espianto della protesi &
\multicolumn{2}{m{14.378cm}|}{\textbf{Risultati: }8 RCT con 526 pazienti, di cui 264 nel gruppo laparoscopico e 253 nel
gruppo open.

{}- \textbf{Recidiva erniaria:} RR = 1.02, 95\% CI 0.41-2.54 (P= 0.97)

{}- \textbf{Durata dell'intervento chirurgico:} Meta-analisi non eseguita per elevata eterogeneità

{}- \textbf{Durata dell'ospedalizzazione:} Meta-analisi non eseguita per elevata eterogeneità

{}- \textbf{Tempo di ritorno a lavoro:} Meta-analisi non eseguita per mancanza di dati

{}- \textbf{Sieroma:} RR = 1.22, 95\% CI 0.38-3.99 (P= 0.74)

{}- \textbf{Complicanze emorragiche:} RR = 0.42, 95\% CI 0.11-1.54 (P= 0.19)

{}- \textbf{Lesioni intestinali: }RR = 1.95, 95\% CI 0.38-9.85 (P= 0.42)

{}- \textbf{Infezione di ferita con espianto della protesi: }RR = 0.22, 95\% CI 0.09-0.54 (P= 0.001)

{}- \textbf{Infezione di ferita senza espianto della protesi}: RR = 0.32, 95\% CI 0.08-1.22 (P= 0.09)}

\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
}%
\bigskip
\end{document}
```

Now, I have to fit the tables in my portrait document and, as I expected, is not that simple.
I figured I had to move all the items of the above preamble in my document preamble, and then insert the tables.

Now the code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tikz}%per la flowchart
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,chains}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{caption}  %per aggiungere captions al PRISMA ed evitare il floating delle tavole
\usepackage{booktabs} % For prettier tables
\usepackage{subfig} %per figure multiple


\usepackage{amsmath}%aggiunto per le tabelle dell'appendice
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,textcomp}%aggiunto per le tabelle dell'appendice

%da qui l'ultima aggiunta
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{hhline}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftex, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, filecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue, pdftitle=, pdfauthor=, pdfsubject=, pdfkeywords=}
% Text styles
\newcommand\textstyleEmphasis[1]{\textit{#1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\arraybslash{\let\\\@arraycr}
\makeatother
%% Page layout (geometry)
%\setlength\voffset{-1in}
%\setlength\hoffset{-1in}
%\setlength\topmargin{2cm}
%\setlength\oddsidemargin{2cm}
%\setlength\textheight{17.001cm}
%\setlength\textwidth{25.7cm}
%\setlength\footskip{0.0cm}
%\setlength\headheight{0cm}
%\setlength\headsep{0cm}
%% Footnote rule
%\setlength{\skip\footins}{0.119cm}
%\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vspace*{-0.018cm}\setlength\leftskip{0pt}\setlength\rightskip{0pt plus 1fil}\noindent\textcolor{black}{\rule{0.25\columnwidth}{0.018cm}}\vspace*{0.101cm}}
% Pages styles
\makeatletter
\newcommand\ps@Standard{
    \renewcommand\@oddhead{}
    \renewcommand\@evenhead{}
    \renewcommand\@oddfoot{}
    \renewcommand\@evenfoot{}
    \renewcommand\thepage{\arabic{page}}
}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{Standard}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1mm}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
%qui finisce l'ultima aggiunta
%ulteriore aggiunta
% Text styles

%fine ulteriore aggiunta
      
   
\definecolor{chaptergrey}{rgb}{0.7,0.7,0.7}

\let\raggedchapter\raggedleft
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}
%\setkomafont{element}{commands}
\setkomafont{title}{\color{cyan}\LARGE}
\addtokomafont{part}{\color{cyan}}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\color{cyan}\LARGE}
\setkomafont{subtitle}{\color{black}}
\addtokomafont{section}{\color{cyan}}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\color{cyan}}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\textbf}
\renewcommand*{\partformat}{\color{cyan}\partname~\thepart}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
    \scalebox{3}{\color{cyan}\thechapter}%
}



%\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\thechapter\autodot\enskip}% If you don't want the chapter name in the running head.


%aggiunto per indentare la TOC
%\usepackage{tocloft}
%\setlength{\cftsecindent}{0pt}% Remove indent for \section
%\setlength{\cftchapindent}{30pt}% Remove indent for \subsection
% \setlength{\cftsubsubsecindent}{0pt}% Remove indent for \subsubsection
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
tocindent=2em
]{chapter}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
tocindent=4em
]{section}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
tocindent=6em
]{subsection}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
    \renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
        {\chapapp\nobreakspace\thechapter}%
    }

}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\author{}

\subject{Linea Guida}
\title{\textbf{Il trattamento laparoscopico di laparocele e ernie ventrali}}
\subtitle{}
\titlehead{}


\date{Gennaio 2022}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{introduzione}




\mainmatter
\part{Sviluppo della linea guida}

\chapter{1}
\chapter{2}


\part{Appendici}

\appendix
\chapter
\rotatebox{90}{%
    \begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
        \begin{flushleft}
            \tablefirsthead{}
            \tablehead{}
            \tabletail{}
            \tablelasttail{}
            \begin{tabular}{|m{3.6139998cm}|m{7.1060004cm}|m{7.0880003cm}m{7.09cm}|}
                \hline
                \multicolumn{4}{|m{25.498001cm}|}{\textbf{Studio:} Forbes SS \textit{et al.} Meta-analysis of randomized controlled
                    trials comparing open and laparoscopic ventral and incisional hernia repair with mesh. British Journal of Surgery
                    2009.}\\\hline
                \textbf{Disegno dello studio}
                
                \textbf{Livello di evidenza} &
                \textbf{Dettagli dello studio/limitazione} &
                \multicolumn{1}{m{7.0880003cm}|}{\textbf{Caratteristiche dei pazienti}} &
                \textbf{Interventi}\\\hline
                \textbf{Disegno dello studio:}
                
                Systematic review e meta-analisi di RCTs
                
                ~
                
                \textbf{Certezza delle prove:}
                
                Bassa
                
                ~
                &
                \textbf{Paesi:} Non applicabile
                
                \textbf{Centri:} Non applicabile
                
                \textbf{Setting: }Ernie ventrali primitive e incisionali
                
                \textbf{Finanziamento}: Non riportato
                
                \textbf{Tasso di dropout: }Non applicabile
                
                \textbf{Limitazioni}:
                
                \textbf{Critical appraisal: }AMSTAR II
                
                ~
                &
                \multicolumn{1}{m{7.0880003cm}|}{Pazienti con ernia ventrale primaria o ernia incisionale
                    
                    ~
                    
                    \textbf{Ricerca bibliografica: }Gennaio 1950 -- Gennaio 2009
                    
                    ~
                    
                    \textbf{Criteri di inclusione: }Studi prospettici randomizzati comparanti la tecnica laparoscopica con quella open,
                    entrambe con l'utilizzo di protesi
                    
                    ~
                    
                    \textbf{Criteri di esclusione:} Studi focalizzati sulla riparazione di ernie inguinali, interventi senza protesi} &
                Tecnica di riparazione laparoscopica vs. a cielo aperto con utilizzo di protesi\\\hline
                \textbf{Note}: &
                \multicolumn{3}{m{21.683998cm}|}{\textbf{Studi inclusi:} Asencio 2008, Barbaros 2007, Carbajo 1999, Misra 2006,
                    Moreno-Egea 2002, Navarra 2007, Olmi 2007, Pring 2008}\\\hline
                \textbf{Outcomes} &
                {}- Recidiva erniaria
                
                {}- Durata dell'intervento chirurgico
                
                {}- Durata dell'ospedalizzazione
                
                {}- Tempo di ritorno a lavoro
                
                {}- Sieroma
                
                {}- Complicanze emorragiche
                
                {}- Lesioni intestinali
                
                {}- Infezione di ferita con espianto della protesi
                
                {}- Infezione di ferita senza espianto della protesi &
                \multicolumn{2}{m{14.378cm}|}{\textbf{Risultati: }8 RCT con 526 pazienti, di cui 264 nel gruppo laparoscopico e 253 nel
                    gruppo open.
                    
                    {}- \textbf{Recidiva erniaria:} RR = 1.02, 95\% CI 0.41-2.54 (P= 0.97)
                    
                    {}- \textbf{Durata dell'intervento chirurgico:} Meta-analisi non eseguita per elevata eterogeneità
                    
                    {}- \textbf{Durata dell'ospedalizzazione:} Meta-analisi non eseguita per elevata eterogeneità
                    
                    {}- \textbf{Tempo di ritorno a lavoro:} Meta-analisi non eseguita per mancanza di dati
                    
                    {}- \textbf{Sieroma:} RR = 1.22, 95\% CI 0.38-3.99 (P= 0.74)
                    
                    {}- \textbf{Complicanze emorragiche:} RR = 0.42, 95\% CI 0.11-1.54 (P= 0.19)
                    
                    {}- \textbf{Lesioni intestinali: }RR = 1.95, 95\% CI 0.38-9.85 (P= 0.42)
                    
                    {}- \textbf{Infezione di ferita con espianto della protesi: }RR = 0.22, 95\% CI 0.09-0.54 (P= 0.001)
                    
                    {}- \textbf{Infezione di ferita senza espianto della protesi}: RR = 0.32, 95\% CI 0.08-1.22 (P= 0.09)}
                
                \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}
}%
\bigskip
%\include{./capitoli/tabelle1a_rev}
\backmatter
% bibliography, glossary and index would go here.

\end{document}
```

However, the output of the table is not centered and looks like this:

[image]

In addition, the commands:

`% Text styles \newcommand\textstyleEmphasis[1]{\textit{#1}} \makeatletter \newcommand\arraybslash{\let\\\@arraycr} \makeatother`

are not recognized

Answer (score 1):

- By use of the `sidewaystable` environment defined in the `rotating` package:
- Please limite your example to an MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document which reproduce your problem and which contents is limit to the problem (almost all preaqmble is not needed, also document body should cobntent only table, as in MWE below)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}   % <---

\begin{document}



\begin{sidewaystable}  % <---
\begin{tabular}{|m{3.6139998cm}|m{7.1060004cm}|m{7.0880003cm}m{7.09cm}|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|m{25.498001cm}|}{\textbf{Studio:} Forbes SS \textit{et al.} Meta-analysis of randomized controlled
        trials comparing open and laparoscopic ventral and incisional hernia repair with mesh. British Journal of Surgery
        2009.}\\\hline
    \textbf{Disegno dello studio}

    \textbf{Livello di evidenza} &
    \textbf{Dettagli dello studio/limitazione} &
    \multicolumn{1}{m{7.0880003cm}|}{\textbf{Caratteristiche dei pazienti}} &
    \textbf{Interventi}\\\hline
    \textbf{Disegno dello studio:}

    Systematic review e meta-analisi di RCTs

    ~

    \textbf{Certezza delle prove:}

    Bassa

    ~
    &
    \textbf{Paesi:} Non applicabile

    \textbf{Centri:} Non applicabile

    \textbf{Setting: }Ernie ventrali primitive e incisionali

    \textbf{Finanziamento}: Non riportato

    \textbf{Tasso di dropout: }Non applicabile

    \textbf{Limitazioni}:

    \textbf{Critical appraisal: }AMSTAR II

    ~
    &
    \multicolumn{1}{m{7.0880003cm}|}{Pazienti con ernia ventrale primaria o ernia incisionale

        ~

        \textbf{Ricerca bibliografica: }Gennaio 1950 -- Gennaio 2009

        ~

        \textbf{Criteri di inclusione: }Studi prospettici randomizzati comparanti la tecnica laparoscopica con quella open,
        entrambe con l'utilizzo di protesi

        ~

        \textbf{Criteri di esclusione:} Studi focalizzati sulla riparazione di ernie inguinali, interventi senza protesi} &
    Tecnica di riparazione laparoscopica vs. a cielo aperto con utilizzo di protesi\\\hline
    \textbf{Note}: &
    \multicolumn{3}{m{21.683998cm}|}{\textbf{Studi inclusi:} Asencio 2008, Barbaros 2007, Carbajo 1999, Misra 2006,
        Moreno-Egea 2002, Navarra 2007, Olmi 2007, Pring 2008}\\\hline
    \textbf{Outcomes} &
    {}- Recidiva erniaria

    {}- Durata dell'intervento chirurgico

    {}- Durata dell'ospedalizzazione

    {}- Tempo di ritorno a lavoro

    {}- Sieroma

    {}- Complicanze emorragiche

    {}- Lesioni intestinali

    {}- Infezione di ferita con espianto della protesi

    {}- Infezione di ferita senza espianto della protesi &
    \multicolumn{2}{m{14.378cm}|}{\textbf{Risultati: }8 RCT con 526 pazienti, di cui 264 nel gruppo laparoscopico e 253 nel
        gruppo open.

        {}- \textbf{Recidiva erniaria:} RR = 1.02, 95\% CI 0.41-2.54 (P= 0.97)

        {}- \textbf{Durata dell'intervento chirurgico:} Meta-analisi non eseguita per elevata eterogeneità

        {}- \textbf{Durata dell'ospedalizzazione:} Meta-analisi non eseguita per elevata eterogeneità

        {}- \textbf{Tempo di ritorno a lavoro:} Meta-analisi non eseguita per mancanza di dati

        {}- \textbf{Sieroma:} RR = 1.22, 95\% CI 0.38-3.99 (P= 0.74)

        {}- \textbf{Complicanze emorragiche:} RR = 0.42, 95\% CI 0.11-1.54 (P= 0.19)

        {}- \textbf{Lesioni intestinali: }RR = 1.95, 95\% CI 0.38-9.85 (P= 0.42)

        {}- \textbf{Infezione di ferita con espianto della protesi: }RR = 0.22, 95\% CI 0.09-0.54 (P= 0.001)

        {}- \textbf{Infezione di ferita senza espianto della protesi}: RR = 0.32, 95\% CI 0.08-1.22 (P= 0.09)}

    \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
As you see, your table is to big to be nicely fit on page. For its body you should consider answers on your previous question.

In the case, that your table is to tall that can be fit in one page, that instead `sidewaystable` you should use `landscape` environment:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{pdflscape}   % <---
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}  % <---
% log table body
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum**
An example of use `landscape` environment with your table where is considered answers on your previous question. Since table is to tall to be fit on one page, it is written as long table using `longtblr` environment defined in `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtblr}%
{
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                  leftmargin=*,
                  after=\end{minipage},                  % <---
                  before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} % <---
                      }
\setlist[description]{nosep,
                  leftmargin=2em,
                  after=\end{minipage},                  % <---
                  before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} % <---
                      }
}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx, varwidth}

\usepackage{pdflscape}   % <---

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}  % <---
   \centering
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Table caption},
  label = {tab:longtblr ...}
                ]{
%            rowhead=1,
            hlines, vlines,
            colspec={X[l,h] *{3}{X[1.5,l,h]}},
            row{2}= {font=\bfseries, f},   % <---
            measure = vbox,                % <===
             }
\SetCell[c=4]{l, wd=\linewidth}    \textbf{Studio:} Forbes SS \textit{et al.}
    Meta-analysis of randomized controlled trials comparing open and
    laparoscopic ventral and incisional hernia repair with mesh.
    British Journal of Surgery  2009.
    &   &   &   \\
Disegno dello studio
Livello di evidenza
    &   Dettagli dello studio/limitazione
        &   Caratteristiche dei pazienti
            &   Interventi              \\
    \begin{description}
\item[Disegno dello studio:]    Systematic review e meta-analisi di RCTs
\item[Certezza delle prove:]    Bassa
    \end{description}
    &   \begin{description}
    \item[Paesi:]   Non applicabile
    \item[Centri:]  Non applicabile
    \item[Setting:] Ernie ventrali primitive e incisionali
    \item[Finanziamento:]       Non riportato
    \item[Tasso di dropout:]    Non applicabile
    \item[Limitazioni:] ?
    \item[Critical appraisal:]  AMSTAR II
        \end{description}
        &   Pazienti con ernia ventrale primaria o ernia incisionale
            \begin{description}
        \item[Ricerca bibliografica:] Gennaio 1950 -- Gennaio 2009
        \item[Criteri di inclusione:] Studi prospettici randomizzati comparanti
        la tecnica laparoscopica con quella open,entrambe con l'utilizzo di protesi
        \item[Criteri di esclusione:]   Studi focalizzati sulla riparazione
        di ernie inguinali, interventi senza protesi
            \end{description}
            &   Tecnica di riparazione laparoscopica vs.
            a cielo aperto con utilizzo di protesi  \\
\textbf{Note}:
    &   \SetCell[c=3]{l, wd=0.6\linewidth}  \textbf{Studi inclusi:}
    Asencio 2008, Barbaros 2007, Carbajo 1999, Misra 2006,
    Moreno-Egea 2002, Navarra 2007, Olmi 2007, Pring 2008   \\*
\textbf{Outcomes}
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item   Recidiva erniaria
    \item   Durata dell'intervento chirurgico
    \item   Durata dell'ospedalizzazione
    \item   Tempo di ritorno a lavoro
    \item   Sieroma
    \item   Complicanze emorragiche
    \item   Lesioni intestinali
    \item   Infezione di ferita con espianto della protesi
    \item   Infezione di ferita senza espianto della protesi
        \end{itemize}
        &   \SetCell[c=2]{l, wd=0.54\linewidth}  \textbf{Risultati:}
            8 RCT con 526 pazienti, di cui 264 nel gruppo laparoscopico e 253
            nel gruppo open.
            \begin{description}
        \item[Recidiva erniaria:] RR = 1.02, \qty{95}{\%} CI 0.41-2.54 (P = 0.97)
        \item[Durata dell'intervento chirurgico:] Meta-analisi non eseguita per elevata eterogeneità
        \item[Durata dell'ospedalizzazione:] Meta-analisi non eseguita per elevata eterogeneità
        \item[Tempo di ritorno a lavoro:] Meta-analisi non eseguit per mancanza di dati
        \item[Sieroma:] RR = 1.22, \qty{95}{\%} CI 0.38-3.99 (P = 0.74)
        \item[Complicanze emorragiche:] RR = 0.42, \qty{95}{\%} CI 0.11-1.54 (P = 0.19)
        \item[Lesioni intestinali:] RR = 1.95, \qty{95}{\%} CI 0.38-9.85 (P = 0.42)
        \item[Infezione di ferita con espianto della protesi:]
            RR = 0.22, \qty{95}{\%} CI 0.09-0.54 \mbox{(P = 0.001)}
        \item[Infezione di ferita senza espianto della protesi:]
        RR = 0.32, \qty{95}{\%} CI 0.08-1.22 \mbox{(P = 0.09)}
            \end{description}
            &   \\
\end{longtblr}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With `sidewaystable` it is nicely rotated, while with `landscape` stays horizontal and it does not rotate. `sidewaystable` seems a good solution. However, to reduce the long dimension of the table I tried to reduce the numbers in `\begin{tabular}{|m{3.6139998cm}|m{7.1060004cm}|m{7.0880003cm}m{7.09cm}|}` and
 `\multicolumn{4}{|m{25.498001cm}|}` but apparently was not enough. What am I missing?

Comment: In the meantime I came up with another solution: I can use the pdf output of the code that you see at the beginning of the post (it looks nice) and add it to the document with `includepdf`. What do you think? It is not as clean as the sidewaystable solution but it works.

Comment: All is up to you. I would do on the showed way.

Comment: I would like too, but I have to find out how to reduce the size of the tables. If I reduce the number in the `tabular` environment (for example reducing `m{7.1060004cm}` to `m{6.1060004cm}` nothing changes

Comment: I show you two ways, but as I see you ignore my suggestion . So, I cant help you further.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not mean to ignore your suggestion that, on the contrary, are precious. I must have missed or I may not have understood that they were solution for the size of the table. I will go back to all the comments again.

Comment: The example just above looks very nice, but I cannot use it because it is on a landscape oriented page, and I have to stay in a portrait page because all the main body of the document is portrait.

Comment: I am re-reading all your comments. With <Addendum An example of use landscape environment with your table where is considered answers on your previous question. Since table is to tall to be fit on one page,`...> do you mean that I should leave the pages with the text in a portrait and those with the table in a landscape orientation?

Comment: @FabioCampanile, yes.

Comment: Ok, I had completely misunderstood your message. It is probably the best solution for a document that will be read on a monitor instead of printing.

Comment: @FabioCampanile In the second example (using environment `landscape`) the table is rotated on a portrait page - note eg. the position of the page number. With package `pdflscape` such pages will be rotated on a monitor. If you print the document, they are still portrait with the rotated table. If you do not want the rotation of such pages on the monitor replace package `pdflscape` by package `lscape`.